# Debian package: postinst error log?

Tags: linux, debian, packaging

I've created *.deb package with a `postinst` script. On some hosts it works with errors:

```
subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Is there a place where these errors are logged so I can have more detailed info (line # and error message, for instance) in order to troubleshoot `postinst` script?

My script has `set -e`, so the error can be anywhere, and the code tells me nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

dpkg can't tell where your script failed -- it's not omniscient.  Your script returned 1, that's all dpkg knows.  The easiest way to debug this is to `set -x` in the script and have all the debugging output dumped that you could possibly wish for.